# SAS/SQL sum amounts distinctly for each group by object?

Tags: sql, sas

I have the following code:

```
proc sql;
CREATE TABLE temp AS 
(SELECT asofdt,
        SUM(CASE WHEN trans_state ='cur_cur' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS _cur_cur,
        SUM(CASE WHEN trans_state ='cur_worse' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS _cur_worse,
        SUM(CASE WHEN trans_state ='cur_pre' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS _cur_pre,
        SUM(CASE WHEN trans_state ='30_better' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS _30_better,
        SUM(CASE WHEN trans_state ='30_30' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS _30_30,
        SUM(CASE WHEN trans_state ='60_90' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS _60_90
FROM PERFORMANCE_TRANS_STATES_CLEAN
GROUP BY asofdt);
run;
```

The problem is it is adding the value from the previous group by asofdt onto the next one. So it is a cumulative sum as I go down the group bys. I would like the sum to be specific to each group by object. Any ideas on how?

Here's a picture of my output.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program seems fine to me. I reproduced it below with fewer observations and did not find that the total was cumulative.

```
data df;
input asofdt MMDDYY8. trans_state $;
datalines;
01/01/16 cur_cur
01/02/16 cur_pre
01/02/16 cur_pre
01/02/16 cur_cur
01/03/16 cur_pre
;
run;

proc sql;
CREATE TABLE temp AS 
(SELECT asofdt,
        SUM(CASE WHEN trans_state ='cur_cur' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS _cur_cur,
        SUM(CASE WHEN trans_state ='cur_worse' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS _cur_worse,
        SUM(CASE WHEN trans_state ='cur_pre' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS _cur_pre,
        SUM(CASE WHEN trans_state ='30_better' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS _30_better,
        SUM(CASE WHEN trans_state ='30_30' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS _30_30,
        SUM(CASE WHEN trans_state ='60_90' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS _60_90
FROM df
GROUP BY asofdt);
quit;
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah it was actually a data issue. The steady progression is what threw me off.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check your data, as this query is fine.  It is indeed running separately on each ASOFDT. You can check that trivially by comparing a single line with a WHERE (`WHERE ASOFDT='01OCT2016'd` or `WHERE ASOFDT='10/01/2016'` depending on the type of that variable).

```
proc sql;
CREATE TABLE temp AS 
(SELECT stock,
        SUM(CASE WHEN month(date)=01 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS _jan,
        SUM(CASE WHEN month(date)=02 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS _feb,
        SUM(CASE WHEN month(date)=03 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS _mar,
        SUM(CASE WHEN month(date)=04 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS _apr
FROM sashelp.stocks
GROUP BY stock);
quit;
```

Nothing about that should be cumulative.  Unless your data is cumulative, which it sort of makes sense it would be with "ASOFDT"?

Comment: Yeah it was actually a data issue. The steady progression is what threw me off.